# Как реализовать скользящее окно на js?

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь решить логическую задачу на js:

На красивом Адриатическом побережье есть n отелей. Каждый отель имеет свою ценность в евро.
Sroljo выиграл евро в лотерее. Теперь он хочет купить последовательность последовательных отелей, так что сумма значений этих последовательных отелей как можно больше - но не выше m.
Вы должны рассчитать эту максимально возможную общую стоимость.
Ввод. В первой строке есть целые числа n и m (1 ≤ n ≤ 300 000, 1 ≤ m <231). В следующей строке есть n натуральных чисел менее 106, представляющих стоимость отеля в том порядке, в котором они лежат вдоль побережья.

Вывод. Распечатайте требуемое число (оно будет больше 0 во всех тестовых данных).
Пример ввода
5 1
2 1 3 4 5
Образец вывода
12

Я решил сделать решение этой задачи через метод скользящих окон. Вот мой код

```js
var A = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5];
var B = [];
var n = 5
var m = 12
big = -1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum=0;
    for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
        sum += A[j];
        if (sum < m) { B[i] = sum; continue; }
        if (sum > m) { B[i] = (sum - A[j]); break; }
        if (sum == m) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (B[i] > big)
        big = B[i];
}
alert(big);
```

Похоже мой я не до конца понял как реализовать этот алгоритм, потому что мой код выводит 10, а не 12. Пожалуйста подскажите, укажите на мои ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

финальное значение sum не записывается в массив B

```
var A = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5];
    var B = [];
    var n = 5
    var m = 12
    big = -1;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum=0;
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            sum += A[j];
            if (sum < m) { B[i] = sum; continue; }//B[i] становится равным сумме
            if (sum > m) { B[i] = (sum - A[j]); break; }
            if (sum == m) {
              B[i] = sum //B[i] становится равным сумме 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (B[i] > big)
            big = B[i];
    }
    alert(big);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите внесённые Вами изменения и зачем они были внесены.

Comment: я не понял сути задачи, но подумав логически пришел к выводу что в каждом условии у тебя B[i] так или иначе изменяется, но в последнем условии когда sum == m цикл просто останавливается без каких либо изменений

Comment: Добавьте пояснения в ответ.

Comment: либо же можно поменять условие sum<m на sum <= m